# How to get GogleMaps apikey for default android debug.keystore with new Google Maps politic

Tags: android, google-maps

I have always used the Google Maps API page to get the API-key also for the debug.keystore file so I could view the maps also in the emulator during test of the app. Now to get the API Key you have to go in Google Api console and create a new project. Is there a way to get API KEY for debug.keystore without create another clone project with different package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just search your `debug.keystore` (in linux is located on `~/.android`) and add it to your current key. To add it, do it as you will do it with a normal keystore getting the SHA1 fingerprint with:

`keytool -list -v -keystore debug.keystore`

You can add several keystores to the same key, just remind to have one fingerprint per line.